# Codeigniter route if methods dont exists

Tags: codeigniter

I am working in a project , after defining my routes like this

```
$route['(:any)/(:num)'] = 'category/index/$2';
```

almost all urls stop working.  i want to apply this route if any controller method doesn't exists. Like if, i want to check all methods before applying this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare this routing at the end. Because If you declare sth like this:

```
$route['(:any)/(:num)'] = 'category/index/$2'; // at the beginning
$route['product/(:num)'] = 'product_id/$2';
$route['user/(:num)'] = 'user_id/$2';
```

all urls like

product/421 user/312 and category/2432 will be showing your category controller and index method.

You can declare default controller in application/config/routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'category';
```

and in your category controller in index method you need to set category ID for ex. $catId = $this->uri->segment(2);

Comment: +1 Also should be checked differences between `$this->uri->segment(n)` and `$this->uri->rsegment(n)` in combination with `$1` or `$2` in right side of routes.